# Show that the linear transformation of a measurable set is measurable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $E\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a Lebesgue measurable set and let $T\colon\mathbb{R}^d\to\mathbb{R}^d$ be a linear transformation.

Show that $T(E)$ is measurable and $m(T(E)) = \left|\det (T)\right|m(E)$.

I can't do it at all, I don't know how to start. Please help me!

Comment: In general if a function $f:\Bbb{R}^d\to\Bbb{R}^d$ is locally Lipschitz, then it sends Lebesgue measurable sets to Lebesgue measurable sets, because every Lebesgue measurable set $E$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets and a zero set: $E=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}K_i\cup Z$. Then, $f(E)=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}f(K_i)\cup f(Z)$; each $f(K_i)$ is compact, and because $f$ is locally Lipschitz, $f(Z)$ has measure zero, hence $f(E)$ is Lebesgue measurable. Now, every linear transformation $T:\Bbb{R}^d\to\Bbb{R}^d$ is automatically Lipschitz, so $T(E)$ is also measurable.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to note that since $T$ is linear, if we define $\mu:=mT$ then $\mu $ is translation invariant so it is a positive multiple of the Lebesgue measure. That is, $mT=cm$. Now we can use $any$ measurable set $E$ to determine $c.$ Thus, if we take the standard cube $Q=[0,1]^n$ and apply $T$ we get a parallelopiped whose volume is [|det T|](https://textbooks.math.gatech.edu/ila/determinants-volumes.html) and since $m(Q)=1$, it follows immediately that $c=|\det T|.$